# ResourceTreeAndListGroup in eclipse 4

Tags: eclipse-rcp, e4

I have a 3.x RCP that I am now moving to E4 using the compatibility layer.

I am now having an issue trying to use `ResourceTreeAndListGroup.getListTable()` which has been removed.

I would go for using Reflection to access the `listViewer`. I was though wondering what is the E4 way of doing it?

Comment: There isn't an e4 way of doing this, this is 3.x compatibility mode code and can't be used in a pure e4 RCP.

Comment: Then I guess my only option is using `Reflection`. I am wondering though what is the equivalent of `ResourceTreeAndListGroup` in E4.

Comment: There isn't an equivalent. A pure e4 RCP can't use things like IResource, IFile, ... or any of the org.eclipse.ui.xxxx plugins.

Comment: @greg-449 what do you mean by "A pure e4 RCP can't use things like IResource, IFile"... I have a few E4 (pure?) apps without the compatibility layer that use them without problem...

Comment: @greg-449 I meant to ask if there is something like `ResourceTreeAndListGroup` functionality wise in E4.

Comment: A pure e4 RCP only uses the plugins in the `org.eclipse.e4.rcp` feature - this does **not** include the `org.eclipse.core.resources` plugin so you can't use IResource etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'pure' e4 RCP only uses the plugins in the `org.eclipse.e4.rcp` feature (and the EMF features that requires).  This feature does not include the `org.eclipse.core.resources` plugin so you can't use `IResource` etc. Consequently there is no equivalent to `ResourceTreeAndListGroup`.

An e4 RCP might use the SWT `FileDialog` and `DirectoryDialog` dialogs for file access, or use the jFace `TreeViewer` and the Java file APIs to build its own dialog.